# Error deployment of project via deploy.sh script

Tags: ruby, continuous-deployment

I need help. I have script for deployment my project on Ruby.

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  ./deploy.sh some_stage_name"
else
    rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`if [ -f .ruby-gemset ]; then cat .ruby-gemset; fi;` do bundle exec cap $@ deploy &&
    cd ./legacy &&
    rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`if [ -f .ruby-gemset ]; then cat .ruby-gemset; fi;` do bundle exec cap $@ deploy &&
    cd ..
fi;
```

If I run it via cap servername deploy then it works. But if i run `./deploy.sh servername` then i get an error.

```
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 1.2.3.4: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

This error i get only on one of my servers. On this server rvm installed global. how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in exec bundle file. I have a comments. After replace all works fine.